# pizza with baking soda instead of yeast

Tags: pizza, yeast, baking-soda, baking-powder

I have a friend who is allergic to yeast so I'm looking for a way to make a pizza dough with baking powder instead of it.
Should I add a bit of lemon juice to counteract the baking soda?

Comment: Chickpea (garbanzo bean flour) Crust Pizza might be a suitable answer here: http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/chickpea-crust-pizza-3414814 No yeast, no baking soda needed. I've made it. It's reasonably good.

Comment: As an alternative, there are quite a number of traditional Italian flatbreads which contain no yeast or baking soda ... the just rely on blistering of the dough.  The cookbook "Savory Baking of the Meditteranean" has a couple recipes for these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make yeast free pizza base using baking powder, it will be a bit crumbly, but it works fine. You could use baking soda, but then as you state you need acid to react with it. Using lemon juice is an option but I would recommend against it as you don't know the exact amount of acidity you'll get and your crust will taste lemony which you don't want. Go get some baking powder instead and use about 3/4 tsp of powder per cup of flour.

You'll want to knead your dough to develop the gluten, otherwise the base will just fall apart.

Comment: The problem is that I can't find baking powder here.I've found something with : E 450, E 500, Reismehl, Maisstärke.

Comment: Where are you @maugch?

Comment: I should also add that the person I mentioned gave me the baking soda, so I don't really want to give it back and say that's better to throw it away.

Comment: germany temporarily

Comment: You should be able to find baking powder in Germany no problem, I suggest you edit your question to include what it's called and how to find it as there are locals on this site who can answer. You could use cream of tartar as an acidity agent if baking powder is unavailable, it's E336.

Comment: @maugch Baking powder is called Backpulver in Germany, and if I remember correctly usually comes in orange packets.

Comment: @maugch should be available in every supermarket, typically in the „baking ingredients“ isle. You want to search for „Backpulver“ and note that it is usually sold in little sachets, often as a pack of five or so. The „name brands are for example „Dr. Oetker“ or „Ruf“, but there are often also store brands available, e.g. Aldi will probably sell only its own brand.

Comment: I will give it a try. How much kneading? I'm used to knead for 15-20min with yeast.

Comment: @maugch and the stuff with E450, E500 and starches is *exactly* what baking powder is: a source of CO2 (baking soda, NaHCO3, the E500) plus an acid (E450). The starches are to keep the rest dry and prevent clumping.

Comment: Kneading is not about time @maugch, but result. 15-20 minutes is a lot to me, but it depends a lot on your technique. You want the dough to be stretchy and elastic, that may take 5 minutes, it could take 20.

Comment: thanks everyone! I will give it a try. I have to give her back all her backing soda then

Comment: +1. My daughter and I made some mini pizzas from a recipe in [a kids' book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Gruffalo-Crumble-Other-Recipes-Donaldson/dp/1509804749) that turned out to use a soda-bread base and they worked very well.  They didn't seem crumbly.  200g flour, 2tsp baking powder, 1tbsp olive oil, 120ml water kneaded for 2 mins and rolled to 5mm.  I was out of baking powder at the time and made some up from baking soda (1/3) and cream of tartar (2/3).